# VHDL - loop failure/'empty' cycle issue

Tags: loops, if-statement, process, vhdl

I'm not so great with VHDL and I can't really see why my code won't work. I needed an NCO, found a working program and re-worked it to fit my needs, but just noticed a bug: every full cycle there is one blank cycle.

[image]

The program takes step for argument (jump between next samples) and clock as trigger.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sinwave_new_01 is
port (clk :in std_logic;
     step :in integer range 0 to 1000;
 dataout : out integer range 0 to 1024
 );
end sinwave_new_01;

architecture Behavioral of sinwave_new_01 is
signal i : integer range 0 to 1999:=0;
type memory_type is array (0 to 999) of integer range 0 to 1024; 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(long and boring array of 1000 samples here);

begin

process(clk)
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then     
dataout <= sine(i);
i <= i+ step;
if(i > 999) then
    i <= i-1000;
end if;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

What do I do to get rid of that zero? It appears every full cycle - every (1000/step) pulses. It's not supposed to be there and it messes up my PWM...
From what I understand the whole block (`dataout` changes, it is increased, and `if i>999 then i<=i-1000`) executes when there is a positive edge of clock applied on the entrance...

BUT it looks like it requires one additional edge to, I don't know, reload it? Does the code execute sequentially, or are all conditions tested when the clock arrives? Am I reaching outside the table, and that's why I'm getting zeroes in that particular pulse? Program /shouldn't/ do that, as far as I understand if statement, or is it VHDL being VHDL and doing its weird stuff again.

How do I fix this bug? Guess I could add one extra clock tick every 1k/step pulses, but that's a work around and not a real solution. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that your variable 'i' exceeds 999 before you reset it.  Remember, you're in a sequential process.  'i' doesn't get the assigned value until the next clock tick AFTER you assign it.

I think if you change this code

```
i <= i + step;
if (i > 999) then
  i <= i-1000;
```

to

```
if ((i + step) > 999) then
  i <= (i + step) - 1000;
else
  i <= i + step;
```

you should get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, just tested it and now its working fine :3
Been working with C and uCs for so long its hard for me to notice stuff like this... being a noob in VHDL isnt helping either.
But now that it works fine I can finally go to bed :D 
Thanks again

Comment: Ironically if `i` WAS a variable, this would work as intended. The "problem" arises because `i` isn't a variable...

Comment: And its... NOT a variable? After all both (variables and signals) are some sort of physical signal when implemented on FPGA, right? I thought they'd work the same... sometimes VHDL is just over my head

Comment: I didn't want to bring up VHDL variables in the solution.  I thought about creating a variable next_i to hold the value of 'i + step' but thought it would just confuse matters.  Generally, it's good idea to stick with non-blocking assignments in sequential processes.  Benji, do a search on 'VHDL signals variables' to read up on the difference.  Always try to have a feel for what hardware your code is implying.  Things that work in simulation don't always work on the hardware otherwise.

Comment: What bout this one? Will it work on the hardware? I got laboratory on monday and this block is a quite huge part of it...

Comment: From the code I see you should be okay.  Basically your entire design is a counter that you're using to address memory locations with.  The counter portion looks fine.  The initial memory contents will show up in your simulation but I would verify that your synthesis tools and FPGA will also initialize the memory to the expected values.  I think that Xilinx/Altera will probably do what you expect but I haven't had to preload memory in a while so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Well, quartus spews out the values OK, so I guess the synthesis should work fine too... case it didnt, whats the name of block I can upload those samples to? Found a block called lpm_rom in quartus, I guess thats the thing Im looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One more thing... 
Does the declaration of *sine* (sample array) actually creates combinatory circuit (bad) or allocates those samples in ROM memory ('good')?